# Threads that stay active (Qt)

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I'm trying to correct a large program for memory leaks and threads that are not stopped. I know I have some, but I'm not sure about how to properly identify and kill them, so I started playing with some canonical examples, and I'm already having those.

First I tried the simplest thing:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    return a.exec();
}
```

That gives me one (1) running thread in the Task Manager.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    WorkerOne *w = new WorkerOne();
    QTimer::singleShot(3456, w, SLOT(stop()));
    return a.exec();
}
```

This one gives me 1 before starting the worker, then 2 until the thread actually starts (`process` is called), then 3 until the `singleShot` signal is captured and the worker deleted and then 2 again. So I'm having something loose there.

And this is the code for `WorkerOne`:

```
WorkerOne::WorkerOne(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
    , m_stop(false) {
    QThread* thread = new QThread;
    this->moveToThread(thread);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(error(QString)), this, SLOT(errorString(QString)));
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(process()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    thread->start();
}

WorkerOne::~WorkerOne() {}

void WorkerOne::process() {
    while(!m_stop) {
        QEventLoop loop; QTimer::singleShot(1000, &loop, SLOT(quit())); loop.exec();
    }
    emit finished();
}

void WorkerOne::stop() {
    m_stop = true;
}

void WorkerOne::errorString(QString err) { }
```

The platform is Qt 5.2.1 with mingw48_32 compiler.

I think I am following the steps in [threading howto from Maya Posch's blog](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/), but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: 1'st thread for `main`, 2'nd for `WorkerOne`, but who created 3'rd one here?

Comment: I tested your code and when I change the single shot timer's timeout from `1000` to `2000`, the number of thread goes from `3` to the expected `2`. For some reason `QTimer::singleShot` is starting a 3rd thread, but not when I increase the timeout to 2000. I have no idea what is happening there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of the worker object is literally upside down. It's `QThread`'s job to spin the event loop. Your worker object should simply be driven by slot calls and incoming events. A processing busy loop idiom uses a zero-length timer to stay active while allowing the event loop to receive events and quit, with no need for extra flags.

Here's how to do it:

```
class WorkerOne : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  QBasicTimer m_timer;
  void processChunk() {
    ...
  }
  void timerEvent(QTimerEvent * ev) {
    if (ev->timerId() == m_timer.timerId()) processChunk();
  }
public:
  WorkerOne(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}
  Q_SLOT void start() { m_timer.start(0, this); }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  WorkerOne worker;
  QThread thread;
  thread.start();
  worker.start();
  worker.moveToThread(&thread);
  a.connect(&thread, SIGNAL(finished()), SLOT(quit()));
  QTimer::singleShot(3456, &thread, SLOT(quit()));
  return a.exec();
}
```

When the timer times out, the thread's event loop quits, the thread finishes, the application's event loop is quit, and, finally, the thread and the worker get destroyed.

A zero-length timer is not really a timer, just an idiom that means: invoke me as soon as the event loop is entered and there's nothing else to do. Doing the below would be a premature pessimization as there's be a memory allocation per each round through the event loop - not using the timer would be worse!

```
class WorkerOne : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_INVOKABLE void processChunk() {
    ...
    // A lame attempt to call ourselves again from the event loop.
    // It works, but has lot more overhead than a zero-length timer!
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "processChunk", Qt::QueuedConnection);
  }
public:
  WorkerOne(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}
  Q_SLOT void start() {
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "processChunk", Qt::QueuedConnection);
  }
};
```

Comment: Actually it should be deleted as the documentation states about the `QThread::finished` signal: [*When this signal is emitted, the event loop has already stopped running. No more events will be processed in the thread, except for deferred deletion events. This signal can be connected to QObject::deleteLater(), to free objects in that thread.*](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qthread.html#finished).

Comment: @thuga Here it doesn't apply at all since there's a direct connection from `finished()` to `deleteLater()` and it will be picked up by the event loop of the thread anyway. I misread the code.

Comment: In a more general case where other workers would be still working, I wouldn't `quit` `QCoreApplication`. Your code, removing that connection, never calls `WorkerOne`'s destructor, and a signal from `&thread`'s `finished()` to `WorkerOne`'s `deleteLater()` would be required. Is that correct?

Comment: @dmcontador Those are all local variables, they are not allocated on the heap. As long as `main()` returns, you're guaranteed that both `WorkerOne` and `QThread` get destructed, in this order. It would be in fact an error to invoke `deleteLater` on either one of those objects. Generally speaking, don't allocate things on the heap unless you need them to be. For class members of `QObject` type, you're welcome to have them as direct class members, not pointer members.

Comment: @KubaOber Will `processChunk` be called in main thread or new thread (becuase of `worker.start` before `worker.moveToThread`)?

Comment: @Bogdan `processChunk` will be called in new thread. Remember that it's called from the event loop. The event loop has no chance to run before the worker gets moved to the new thread - your code is running then, after all.